# How to remove a file from an Eclipse project without deleting the file from the disk?

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to remove a file from an Eclipse project without actually deleting the file from the disk?

Is there a reason why adding/removing files to/from a project is so tightly connected with what happens to the corresponding files on the disk?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can filter out file system resources you don't want Eclipse to see. To do that, right click on the folder, go into Properties and then under Resource -> Resource Filters.

Comment: Thank you. It seems the issue is that Eclipse doesn't keep a list of files associated with a project, it simply considers all of the files in the project directory to be in the project (which makes having files in the directory but not in the project quite complicated, i.e. requiring using resource filters).

Comment: Note that you can also link folders into project from another location on disk. This allows you to create projects in a clean location and link in the folders that you need. See advanced button in the new folder wizard.